# React Component wont render with given state from the parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I need to render a component that has a route using react router. the first component has a button that when clicked needs to render another component that has state passed in from the first component. All objects and strings from the first component show in the console.log of the child component but it wont set state when I use setProfile(p).

```
    const Member = (props)=> {  
      const [user, setUser] = useState({});
      const [profile, setProfile] = useState({});
    
   // run effect when user state updates
    useEffect(() => {
      const doEffects = async () => {
        try {

          const pro = socialNetworkContract.members[0]
          console.log(pro)
          const p = await incidentsInstance.usersProfile(pro, { from: accounts[0] });
          const a = await snInstance.getUsersPosts(pro, { from: accounts[0] });
          console.log(a)
      console.log(p)
      setProfile(p)

        } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }
    doEffects();
  }, [profile, state]);

  const socialNetworkContract = useSelector((state) => state.socialNetworkContract)

  return (
    <div class="container">

                <a target="_blank">Name : {profile.name}</a>

        {socialNetworkContract.posts.map((p, index) => {
          return <tr key={index}>
{p.message}
        </tr>})}
      </div>
  )
}

export default Member;
```

This is the parent component I want to redirect from

```
   const getProfile = async (member) => {
        const addr = dispatch({ type: 'ADD_MEMBER', response: member })
        console.log(member)
    }


  const socialNetworkContract = useSelector((state) => state.socialNetworkContract)

    
      return (
          <div>
            {socialNetworkContract.posts.map((p, index) => {
              return <tr key={index}>
    
      <button onClick={() => getProfile(p.publisher)}>Profile</button>
    
            </tr>})}
          </div>
      )
    }
export default withRouter(Posts);
```

I have this component working when I don't have a dynamic route that needs data passing in from the parent component It's redirecting from.

This is my routes.js file

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/posts" exact component={Posts} />
      <Route path="/member" exact component={Member} /> 
        <Redirect exact to="/" />
      </Switch>
  )
}

export default Routes
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-pine-tuxxb

Comment: This is the same as your other question, isn't it?

Comment: But what is the homepage supposed to be?  You redirect to `"/"` but there is no `Route` for that path.